# Fixing Binary search bug from Bentley's book (programming pearls: writing correct programs)

Tags: java, algorithm, overflow, binary-search

Binary search can be implemented in many ways-recursive, iterative, conditionals, etc. I took this from Bentley's book "**Programming pearls**: Writing correct programs" which is an iterative implementation, and that includes a bug.

```
 public class BinSearch 
    {
       static int search( int [] A, int K ) {
          int l = 0;
          int u = A. length -1;
          int m;
          while ( l <= u ) {
              m = (l+u) /2;
              if (A[m] < K){
              l = m + 1;
              } else if (A[m] == K){
                    return m;
              } else {
                    u = m-1;
              }
         }
    return -1;
    }
}
```

I found a bug in the line m = (l+u) /2; it can lead to overflow. How can we avoid this overflow in this binary search?

Comment: Should not `while ( l <= U )` be `while ( l <= u )` instead ?

Comment: i took it from the book...programming pearls:writing correct programs.

Comment: `U` will be unknown identifier and `u` makes a lot more sense. Have you not tried to compile it?

Comment: This issue was identified several years ago - some analysis exists at http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: Usually set m = l + (u - l) / 2; is just fine. The key principle of binary search is keep precondition unchanged in your binary operation halving the interval.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

change

`m = (l+u) /2`

to

`m = (u-l) / 2 + l`

The reason why the `(l+u) / 2` can overflow becomes obvious if you consider a very large array of 2^31 - 1 elements (maximum value a signed 32-bit integer can hold).
In this case the first iteration is just fine because `2^31 - 1 + 0` is not a big deal but consider the case of `l = m + 1` here. In the second iteration u is still the same and l is `2^31 / 2` so `l + u` will lead to an overflow.

This way we are avoiding the addition of `u + l` by first determining the relative middle between l and u `(u - l) / 2` and then adding the lower number l to it so it becomes absolute. So during the operation `m = (u-l) / 2 + l;` we never exceed the value of u.

To summarize the complete code:

```
public class BinSearch 
{
    static int search( int [] A, int K ) 
    {
        int l = 0;
        int u = A. length -1;
        int m;

        while ( l <= u ) 
        {
            m = (u-l) / 2 + l;

            if (A[m] < K)
                l = m + 1;
            else if (A[m] == K)
                return m;
            else
                u = m - 1;
        }
        return -1;
     }
}
```

Comment: Technically this problem can occur on an array with anywhere between `2^30(+1?)` and `2^31-1` elements.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose l and u are int both fall into [0, 2^31-1]. 
If l, u >= 2^30, then (l+u) >= 2^31 is overflow. To avoid this, use

```
m = l + (u-l)/2;
```

instead. What is more, it may be more reasonable to write binary search like this:

```
    public class BinSearch 
    {
        static int search( int [] A, int K ) {
            int l = -1;             // index lower bound shift left by 1
            int u = A.length;       // index upper bound shift right by 1
            int m;
            while ( l + 1 < u ) {
                m = l + (u-l)/2;    // avoid overflow
                if (A[m] < K){
                    l = m;          // keep A[l] < K 
                } else {
                    u = m;          // keep A[u] >= K
                }
            }
            if ( (u == A.length) || (A[u] != K) ) return -1;
            return u;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

As several others have said, the fix is simple, certainly the simplest I've seen for a 100-point bounty!  Here is another, which has a nice symmetry, even if it takes a few more clock cycles:

```
m = (l >> 1) + (u >> 1) + (l & u & 1);
```

You should not malign Bentley for "a bug" until you have better information. When he wrote that article for the ACM (some time in the 1980's I think), he was pseudocoding and writing in 32-bit C; machines with gigabytes of RAM didn't exist.  Even if they had, with 4-byte ints, a 32-bit machine can't have an array with more than 2^28 ints.  Therefore the highest possible index is 2^28-1.  Doubling this value does *not* cause an in `int` to overflow.

Of course, it's exactly the same with 32-bit Java.  You need the broken kludge of 64-bit Java - a language that allows objects of size approaching 2^64 but limits indices to 2^32-1 in order to cause this "bug" to appear.

What you call a bug is a change of operating assumptions. Every program in the universe will manifest some kind of flaw if the environment changes in the right way.

Comment: Readers of the book would have included coders for embedded devices using 16-bit integers.  I would call it a bug, especially since it is in expository form.

And I suspect Bentley would too.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
m = (l+u) / 2
```

to

```
m = l + (u - l) / 2
```

It is trivial to see that both is equal and also the second statement prevents the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change u = m-l; to u = m -1.

it's 1 not l.
---------addtion------
cause (l+u) may be greater than 2^31-1 (if the int is 32bits), so it may overflow. so you should change (l+u)/2 to l+((u-l)>>1), and u-l cannot be greater than 2^31-1.

Answer (score 1):

The iterative implementation binary search indeed has a bug. change `m = (l+u)/2` . As others have mentioned it can lead to integer overflow. Replace that by `m = l + (u-l)/2`.

From experience I have time and again seen buggy binary search implementations. Binary search although a simple concept involving divide and conquer can be difficult to get right. Its easy to change the above `m` assignment. Hope this helps...

Comment: Why not "m = l/2 + u/2" ? This would also prevent overflow, isn't it? However, divide operation is performed twice. What do you say?

Comment: @stalin Consider the case where both L,U are odd.

Comment: @netanelw: Yes, I didn't think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Although Machtl and others have already written the way to overcome the overflow bug but adding just for the sake of completeness

1. Use **int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;** faster way
2. And in C and C++ (where we don't have the >>> operator)
   **mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1;**